# Cefsharp: Prevent page from reloading after first load

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am using `Cefsharp` and I want to be able to stop the page from reloading after it has loaded. The page uses `jQuery` to reload the page. I do not want any reloads to be carried out after it has been loaded for first time. In other words, I want to prevent the page from being reloaded after it has been loaded while staying on the page.

Comment: That's likely going to be a tricky one. See if implementing a `RequestHandler` provides the callback you need, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#protocol-execution for the basic usage pattern. `OnBeforeBrowse` might work, there's also other methods on the class that might work. Otherwise you might need to execute some javascript to modify the behaviour of the web page itself.